sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: movie.rating
Good day
I have created the following table on SQLite 3 using SQLAlchemy on my python program.
class Movie(db.Model):
id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
year: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=False)
rating: Mapped[float] = mapped_column(Float, nullable=True)
ranking: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=True, autoincrement=True)
review: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=True)
img_url: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=False)

I am trying to add a new row on my SQLite table with the information retrieved from a url by excuting this code below: (Please note the only information supplied is for the column which have the nullable set to False on my SQLite Database columns)
@app.route("/find")
def find_movie():
movie_api_id = request.args.get("id")
if movie_api_id:
    movie_api_url = f"{MOVIE_DB_INFO_URL}/{movie_api_id}"
    response = requests.get(movie_api_url, params={"api_key": MOVIES_API_KEYS, "language": "en
       US"})
    data = response.json()
    new_movie = Movie(
        title=data["title"],
        year=data["release_date"].split("-")[0],
        img_url=f"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500{data['poster_path']}",
        description=data["overview"]
    )
    db.session.add(new_movie)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for("rate_movie", id=new_movie.id))

And I receive this error message below when I run the code
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: movie.rating
[SQL: INSERT INTO movie (title, year, description, rating, ranking, review, img_url) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Gladiator', '2000', "In the year 180, the death of emperor Marcus Aurelius throws the Roman Empire into chaos.  Maximus is one of the Roman army's most capable and truste ... (168 characters truncated) ... e traders.  Renamed Spaniard and forced to become a gladiator, Maximus must battle to the death with other men for the amusement of paying audiences.", None, None, None, 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ty8TGRuvJLPUmAR1H1nRIsgwvim.jpg')]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)

It looks as if you initially created the column with nullable=False (or NOT NULL in the create table statement). You will need to amend the column to fix it. The simplest approach is to drop and recreate the table.

@snakecharmerb I receive the error message for the columns where I have set the nullable=True and which my code does not provide values for.

Then your column definitions don't match the definitions in the database. This is most likely because you have changed the model definition after creating he table.  You need to drop and recreate the table.

Did you try dropping the table and recreating it ? Because that sql error won't lie to you ;-)

@snakecharmerb I couldn't understand your first comment but after I recreated the table, it worked fine! Thanks

Remarkably similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72335001/5320906

You will probably need to create your table again from scratch.
You might have created it before setting this nullable to True.
If it does not work you can show here the sql code executed for table creation.
